# Why is the 'plink' noise in chat not an account setting?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, alerts

First, let's explain what I am on about. That little 'plink' noise you get by default when some one posts a message at you on chat. I **HATE** it with a passion! At first I was ok with the noise, as I could simply disable it and problem solved.

Except it's not solved, it is merely put aside for a while. If I use another computer, or if the cookie runs out, the bane of chat returns with it's shrill annoying chime.

Why is this setting not a user account setting? Why is it done as some shoddy cookie based setting that does not carry from one machine to another and is reset regularly? There is no need for this rage to be induced every month!

Comment: What about people that want plinks on one machine but not on another?

Comment: Simple, keep the cookie based system, but allow an account setting that can provide the default value. In my case, no plink.

Comment: My computer has volume control buttons. Also, pulseaudio (linux) and Win7 let you change volume level per application?

Comment: Obviously a system wide silence is not the solution, else I wouldn't have speakers/head phones. Per application is one possible solution, but does not solve this problem when using multiple computers. You still have to configure this setting per machine.

Comment: Also, if you disable the sound for the whole browser you can't use any streaming app anymore.

Comment: Semi-related: [Chat notification sounds have become like icicles repeatedly driven through my ears](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139213/chat-notification-sounds-have-become-like-icicles-repeatedly-driven-through-my-e)

Comment: @sehe another problem with per-application is that many people use their browser to play other audio (podcasts, youtube etc). So I don't want to disable all sounds in my browser, just the ones coming from SE chat.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: is that really a common use case? I'd assume it is way more common for people to have one preferred setting that they want all their computers to use forever

Comment: @sehe: Yeah, I want to turn off all sounds for my PC or even just my browser, just for SO chat.