# Why can't it just stay off?

Tags: bug, chat, notifications, audio

I hate that 'plink' chat notification with infinite rage. The most blessed feature in my opinion is the ability to turn off that audible scar. I have [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155399/why-is-the-plink-noise-in-chat-not-an-account-setting) before for this setting to be stored as part of site profile so that I never have to suffer that pain when I go to a different computer, but *apparently* fixing that mistake is not high on the priority list.

I can live with that, I only have hulk smash everything once, then I know to turn it off on a new machine, which thankfully is not that often. It's still wrong, but I can tolerate it being a  cookie setting.

At least, I could. That plink noise has evolved into some sort of herpes like virus, I can treat the symptoms but sooner or later, it flares up and I get plinked one more time. Yes, that inbred idea of a notification noise every so often decides to twist my nipples jus one more time and rings through my head. I can't afford all the pens I end up destroying as I spasm at once again being violated.

This has to be fixed. That noise is a curse of humanity and must be stopped. Clearly cookies  can not be trusted to keep it at bay. Perhaps it can be reversed to be an opt-in feature for those few people sadistic enough to bring that mess into their lives.

Ideally, that noise would be just removed from the chat system entirely, and the person who first thought it was a decent enough idea ground to death between two giant rollers feet first, slowly enough to keep him alive whilst he hears his bones crushing all the way up his body.

Comment: +1 this can be really annoying. I don't mind keeping it opt out as long as you can turn it off on a user level.

Comment: +1 I don't use chat, but I can feel your rage and now understand that the solution to world peace is to remove the `plink`.

Comment: +1 I don't use chat either, but your text made me laughing to tears! You've just made my day, thank you! :>

Comment: I sent you a handful of chat messages to fully express my support

Comment: ¬_¬ I wish people would stop ---correcting my mistakes--- removing my rage markers

Comment: but not quite as much as I wish markdown worked in comments. Urge to kill rising!

Comment: I use chat on multiple computers too.  At work I turned the "plink" off because, you know, cube farms, but at home I leave it turned on because I might be in the room but not at my desk and I'd like to know if someone's trying to reach me.  Tying it to the account rather than to the browser would break that.  I turned the "plink" off once at work, months ago.  Do you use so many different computers that this is really a burden?

Comment: Chat has a very pleasant *boing* noise. The weird *plink* is specific to SO and MSO, which are for some reason separate from the standard SE chat.

Comment: IMO the chat.so sound is okay, but I *hate* the chat.se sound.

Comment: Last time I was in MSO chat (yesterday) it seemed to have a 2370s door chime sound. That was nice.

Comment: <slight explosions of rage> It does not matter what it sounds like, what matters is that turning it off is BROKEN and a risk to humanity!