# Can we have a kinder, gentler *THUD*?

Tags: feature-request, chat, audio

The current notification sound for the Super User chat, while rather effective can often quite startling, especially when you're doing something else, or just not expecting it. Could we have some way of choosing a less.. ***THUD***dy sound, or volume control for it, for systems with no per-program volume control?

Comment: Which chat? There are different notification sounds for different chats.

Comment: Super user, never trying drinking juice while in there.

Comment: How about [this sound?](http://butifnot.tripod.com/racecar.html)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's not a dup. It's about volume. This Q is about the actual sound

Comment: The massive thud I've heard on rootaccess (SU's main room), comms room (SF's main room), and nearly every other chat I can recall being on. I suppose its the default THUD, though other rooms may have different sounds, maybe less THUDdy than this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Stack Overflow's is just a little *plink* sound. :P

Comment: [But, we brought that machine in for when the Administrator shows up!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=arCITMfxvEc)

Comment: ... BIAS!... Thats *exactly* what I mean by a less thuddy alternative!

Comment: @JackManey that's *PING*, not *plink*.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - How about [one ping only](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jr0JaXfKj68)?

Comment: @JackManey no, those are the measurements of the playmate of the month.

Comment: I've always heard it as more of a "bowmf"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once again quoting [myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139222/115866):

> Oh, and regarding the discussion about the sound choice [...], I'll say what I've said time and time again: Anything that is not *constructive* is in vain. Opinions on particular sounds are more subjective than on Jarrod's toe socks, so to change a notification sound, you have to a) offer an alternative, not just "the current one is bad, give us another one", and b) there has to be reasonable agreement that the new choice isn't worse than the old one. In such a case, we're happy to change notification sounds. The sounds for the no-longer-existing sites are still there, so you even have some suggestions to start with ([1](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/sf.mp3), [2](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/su.mp3), [3](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/bonfire.mp3), [4](http://or.cdn.sstatic.net/chat/ubuntu.mp3)).