# Did the chat *PING* get louder?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, ping

The sound when someone pings me seems to have gotten louder and almost blasted my ears off (I have headphones on)

Is there any way to change the volume of it?

I still want it **on** but at a ***MUCH* lower** volume.

---

Or can we please have the option to set the volume that **we** want for chat inside of chat?

Comment: Maybe [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139213/152859) has returned in full volume?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd that _is_ possible... but now I have a major headache from it... Where do I send the Advil receipt?

Comment: Kind of a hack, but this script'll do it: `document.getElementById('jp_audio_0').volume=0.1;`.

Comment: @SuperScript annoying because that means I will have to run it **every time** i load chat...

Comment: You could make a userscript (Greasemonkey for Firefox : http://greasespot.net/, Scriptish for Chrome : http://userscripts.org/).  But as I said, it's a hack.

Comment: What do you mean @MirkoCianfarani ?

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani I am quite confused... I have headphones on.

Answer (score 3):

No, there have been no changes even remotely connected to audio in chat.

Most modern OSes allow you to change sound volume on a per-app level; any chance your browser's volume was turned up in that mixer?

Comment: Not that I know of @balpha. Is there any way to change the volume **in chat**?

Comment: No, unless you count turning it off as changing the volume.

Comment: Well that is a part of my [meta-tag:feature-request], so for now this is not the answer to my OP

Comment: This thread needs a userscript.